# Help used Bochner integral for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $G$ be a compact group, and $H$ be Hilbert. Let $U$ be a unitary representation of $G$ on $H$(it's a group homomorphism from $G$ into the unitary operators of $H$). Define $E$ on $\mathbf{B}_0(\mathcal{H})$(compact operators on $H$) by $$E(T) := \int_G U_xTU_x^* dx$$Because $\mathcal{H}$ is Banach, then $\mathbf{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is Banach so we can use the Bochner integral. I am not used to the Bochner integral, can someone help me integrate this? I am trying to show that $E(T)$ is a compact operator. I have already established that $U_xTU_x^*$ is compact due to $T$ being compact and unitary representation.

I would like to mention that $x \mapsto U_xTU_x^*$ is norm continuous on the norm of $\mathbf{B}(H)$(edit)

Another edit, we are using thee Haar measure on $G$

Comment: Your question is a little weird. Even if you're not very familiar with the Bochner integral, you should probably already know that the Bochner integral of a function with values in a Banach space (here $\mathbf B_0(H)$), when it exists, is an element of that Banach space.

Comment: @P.P.Tuong Oh I see lmao, this makes total sense even though it was super obvious. I don't know why, but I just assumed without must thought our overall Banach space was the bounded operators. Thanks